# How to change the colour of a certain bar in a bar chart in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following bar chart:

[image: current graph]

I did this by using the following code:

```
NL_population <- ggplot(data = NL, aes(reorder(Country, -`Population (g)`, sum), `Population (g)`)) + 
  geom_col(fill = "#0099f9") +
  labs(title = "Average population growth in %",
       subtitle = "Years: 2017-2021",
       x = "",
       y = "Population growth") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(NL$`Population (g)`), linetype = "dashed", size = 1) + coord_flip()
```

I would like to have the Netherlands another colour than the other countries. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Check out [`gghighlight`](https://yutannihilation.github.io/gghighlight/index.html)

Comment: You could add (dplyr::mutate) a column in the NL dataset that consists of hex colour codes, then read that column in via ggplot::scale_fill_manual. EDIT: Stefan below has provided the full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the option mentioned by @shafee in his comment a simple approach would be to map a condition for the country to highlight on the `fill` aes and set the your desired colors via `scale_fill_manual`.

Using some fake example data based on the `gapminder` dataset:

```r
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

countries <- c("Netherlands", "Italy", "Belgium", "United States", "Iceland", "Ireland")

NL <- gapminder |>
  filter(year %in% c(2007, 2002), country %in% countries) |>
  group_by(Country = country) |>
  summarise(`Population (g)` = 100 * (last(pop) / first(pop) - 1))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = NL, aes(reorder(Country, -`Population (g)`, sum), `Population (g)`)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Country != "Netherlands")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "#0099f9"), guide = "none") +
  labs(
    title = "Average population growth in %",
    subtitle = "Years: 2017-2021",
    x = "",
    y = "Population growth"
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(NL$`Population (g)`), linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
  coord_flip()
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
```

[image]